Dataframe rows to columns without values to aggregate
I'd like to reshape the below Pandas Dataframe - I'd like to use the values in the 'rank' column as columns.
From:

To:

What's the easiest way to achieve this? I've thought about using unstack() but haven't been able to achieve the result I wanted. Methods such as pivot/pivot_table seem to require there to be values to aggregate.

You do not need aggregation with pivot. pivot_table is the one that aggregates.
